# Issue on Applying CSS to Append Function on Element Creation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/paeSL/) and let me know how to fix the issue on this code?

```
<div id="out"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colors = new Array("#FFF", "#CCC", "#7FFF00");
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        $("#out").append('<div class="box"></div>');
        $(".box").css("background-color",colors[0]);
    }
});
</script>
```

what I am trying to do is generating div elements based on an array length and set the background of them from the colors array

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, inside the loop, you are targetting all `.box` elements instead of targetint the element which was recently added.

You can use [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead to return the recently added element and use that reference to make the css changes

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colors = new Array("#FFF", "#CCC", "#7FFF00");
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        var $el = $('<div class="box">1</div>').appendTo("#out");
        $el.css("background-color", colors[i]);//also need to use the index of the array instead of the hard coded 0
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cyh8e/)

Also try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var colors = new Array("#FFF", "#CCC", "#7FFF00");
    $.each(colors, function (i, color) {
        var $el = $('<div class="box">1</div>').appendTo("#out");
        $el.css("background-color", color);
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cyh8e/2/)

Comment: Wow! Thanks Arun, this was supper fast! I need 10 more minutes to accept your reply!

Comment: just can you please let me know why did you used appendto instead of append?

Comment: @user3674990 because `.append()` returns the reference to the `#out` element which is not what we wants.... while `.appendTo()` returns the reference to the newly created element which can be used for further modification.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `i` no `0`

```
$(".box").css("background-color",colors[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks C-link but this just generate boxes with one color(last code from the array)